# Why are items inside an Array() dependent? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

I did:

```
a = Array(2).fill([]);
a[0].push(1);
```

Expected outcome: `a = [[1], []]`
Got: `a = [[1], [1]]`

Why does the second item depend on the first one here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs,

> If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will
> reference that object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Alternate using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const a = Array.from({length: 2}, i => [])

a[0].push(1)

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to `.fill()` passes a **single** empty array. Thus, that same array is dropped into all the elements of the filled array.

Consider that if you called `Array(2).fill(3);` all the elements would contain the value 3. It's really no different here.